# How to count instances of duplicate characters within a string?

Tags: r, duplicates, character

I have a dataframe:

```
levels     counts
1, 2, 2        24
1, 2           20
1, 3, 3, 3     15
1, 3           10
1, 2, 3        25
```

I want to treat, for example, "1, 2, 2" and "1, 2" as the same thing. So, as long as there is a "1" and "2" without any other character, it will count as the level "1, 2". Here is the desired data frame:

```
levels     counts
  1, 2         44
  1, 3         25
  1, 2, 3      25
```

Here is code to reproduce the original data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(levels = c("1, 2, 2", "1, 2", "1, 3, 3, 3", "1, 3", "1, 2, 3"), 
                 counts = c(24, 20, 15, 10, 25))
df$levels <- as.character(df$levels)
```

Comment: Have you looked into sets? The set data structure does not store duplicate elements and would be good for your issue.

Answer (score 6):

Split `df$levels`, get the unique elements, and then sort it. Then use that to obtain aggregate of `counts`.

```
df$levels2 = sapply(strsplit(df$levels, ", "), function(x)
    paste(sort(unique(x)), collapse = ", "))   #Or toString(sort(unique(x))))
aggregate(counts~levels2, df, sum)
#  levels2 counts
#1    1, 2     44
#2 1, 2, 3     25
#3    1, 3     25
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution uses `tidyverse`. `df2` is the final output.

```
library(tidyverse)

df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(ID = 1:n()) %>%
  mutate(levels = strsplit(levels, split = ", ")) %>%
  unnest() %>%
  distinct() %>%
  arrange(ID, levels) %>%
  group_by(ID, counts) %>%
  summarise(levels = paste(levels, collapse = ", ")) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(levels) %>%
  summarise(counts = sum(counts))
```

#### Update

Based on comments below, a solution using ideas similar to d.b

```
df2 <- df %>% 
  mutate(l2 = map_chr(strsplit(levels, ", "), 
                      .f = ~ .x %>% unique %>% sort %>% toString)) %>%
  group_by(l2) %>% 
  summarise(counts = sum(counts))
```

Comment: Or more directly translated from @d.b: `df %>% group_by(levels2 = strsplit(levels, ", ") %>% sapply(. %>% unique %>% sort %>% toString)) %>% summarise(counts = sum(counts))`

Comment: @Frank Maybe we could replace `sapply` by the more tidyverse-esque `map_chr()`.. something like: `df %>% group_by(l2 = map_chr(strsplit(levels, ","), .f = ~ .x %>% unique %>% sort %>% toString)) %>% summarise(counts = sum(counts))`

Comment: @StevenBeaupré Thanks for the comments. I have updated my post based on your and Frank's suggestions.

Comment: @ycw You can skip the `mutate()` and use `group_by(l2 = ...)` directly

Comment: @StevenBeaupré I know. Thanks for showing that. I just don't want the `group_by` call becomes too long. Sometimes it is nice to show the intermediate steps.